# Como testar de forma eficaz e localizar as falhas de segurança da aplicação?

Tags: segurança, testes

Estou enfrentando um serio problema com hackers e/ou crackers no site desenvolvido pra uma prefeitura. Fiz testes com `SQL MAP` em todas as páginas do site. testei o bloqueio a ftp, procurei por arquivos injetados dentro do site, procurei vírus, Malwares e backdoors e até agora nada...

Então me surgiu essa questão, como testar a aplicação de forma eficaz e localizar as falhas de segurança relacionada exclusivamente á aplicação?

Acho que pra não ficar tão ampla a questão poderia ser focado apenas em relação ao ambiente WEB... caso a pessoa que responda a pergunta ache que pode abranger todo o conteúdo ela será muito bem vinda também :D

Gostaria também que se possível que a resposta fosse de forma bem genérica podendo-se aplicar a qualquer forma de desenvolvimento(dentro das limitações das linguagens)

> **Informações sobre a aplicação:** 
>
>   Linguagem: PHP 
>   Banco de Dados: MySQL 
>   Conexões: mysql_connect ¬¬ (não é culpa minha)
>
> Foco dos Ataque: Banco de Dados
>
> **Problemas comuns** 
>   Injeção de script para redirecionamento da página 
>   Injeção de imagens dentro das notícias e destaques 
>   Injeção de arquivos para backdoor
>
> **Itens que não causam problemas(não ouve tentativas)**
>   Ataques de DoS
>   Ataques de Brute-Force
>
> **Correções em primeira instancia**
>   Troca das credenciais do banco de dados
>   Troca da senha de administrador (Hash atual -> df8bce1285196dddc104c22f15665dac)

Já havia perguntado [O que o código abaixo(escrito por um cracker) faz?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8721/o-que-o-c%C3%B3digo-abaixo-escrito-por-um-cracker-faz) e havia postado o código de um dos arquivos que já foram injetados dentro do site...

Fiz uma varredura na ftp e me certifiquei de que não existe nenhum arquivo malicioso dentro dela...

Todos os gets e posts são validados da seguinte forma

```
if(isset($_GET['t'])){
    $ids = (int)mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['t']);
    if(!is_numeric($ids)){
        $ids = '1';
    }   
} else {
    $ids = '1'; 
}
```

Comment: Então dê mais informações sobre seu problema, sua estrutura, etc.

Comment: @bigown nesse caso, não sei bem quais informações são necessárias para avaliar(gostaria até que fosse da forma mais genérica possivel) se puder me auxiliar dizendo quais as informações são mais vitais para poder responder

Comment: O que exatamente aconteceu? A aplicação é escrita em que linguagem de programação? Você citou SQL, o ataque foi no banco de dados?

Comment: @Andrey adicionei a pergunta

Comment: Está procurando no lugar errado. Leia mais sobre segurança em aplicação no projeto [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: Quais exatamente os problemas que você está tendo? Os tipos de vulnerabilidade a que uma aplicação pode estar exposta são muitos e bastante diversos, uma resposta genérica seria ou por demais superficial ou por demais extensa. Se não tiver como descrever o problema com mais detalhes, pelo menos diga quais problemas você **não está** enfrentando (ex.: DoS, sequestro de sessão, roubo de identidade, injeção de JS, injeção de shell...). Claro que não dá pra ter certeza que uma vulnerabilidade não existe, mas pelos "sintomas" pode-se restringir o foco de análise às suas prováveis causas.

Comment: Bem, se a vulnerabilidade afeta o banco, você pode começar alterando as credencias do DB e migrar a camada da aplicação para PDO/mysqli e começar a usar [*prepared statments*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @gmsantos seria um sonho pode fazer isso, mas por questões contratuais e discordância entre a empresa e a prefeitura não posso gastar o dia substituindo todas as conexões para `prepared statments` :'(

Comment: Rodrigo essa discordância é do tipo *Cliente:* "Vocês quem fizeram ou vocês que assumiram a bucha, arrumem de graça" ?

Comment: @gmsantos é do tipo "vocês fizeram, não temos culpa se nossos funcionários sabotam o próprio sistema"... obs: a maior suspeita até o momento é que seja uma briga entre os servidores publicos, já aconteceu com outro site de prefeitura ¬¬

Comment: Estamos trabalhando para corrigir as falhas porem o site é relativamente antigo, uma atualização desse tamanho requer muito tempo(não dispomos de equipe sobrando pra isso) e de graça com certeza não será feito...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com sua descrição dos problemas mais comuns, eu dividiria a atenção em duas frentes:

> Injeção de script para redirecionamento da página
>
> Injeção de imagens dentro das notícias e destaques

Isso é sinal de que as entradas do usuário não estão sendo sanitizadas de modo apropriado. Mas nesse caso, não estou me referindo a formatar corretamente o SQL (algo que *prepared statements* ajudaria), mas sim em escapar corretamente o **HTML**.

Em uma aplicação Web há vários pontos em que uma entrada fornecida pelo usuário é mostrada de volta para ele como parte de uma página. Mesmo que essa entrada seja corretamente "escapada" ao inserir no banco, isso não significa que ela é segura para ser incorporada numa página. Por exemplo, não há caracteres SQL inválidos na string `<script>alert(1);</script>`. Mas se um usuário entrou **isso** em um campo de texto, o que deve ser incluído numa página de resultados é `&lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt;`

(dados a serem retornados com valores de um `input` tampouco estão seguros. Ex.: `teste"><img src="foo`)

Escapar conteúdo antes de mandar pro banco previne **SQL Injection**. Para prevenir contra **JS Injection** (ou HTML Injection) é necessário sanitizar também o conteúdo que **sai do banco**. Eu concentraria meus esforços nesse sentido, pois seus "sintomas" não são característicos de um problema na entrada de dados/consultas (ex.: vazamento de informação), e sim na saída dos mesmos.

> Injeção de arquivos para backdoor

Até onde meu conhecimento vai, isso não é algo que possa ser causado por falhas no banco, mas sim no *upload* de arquivos. Uma situação comum é um site que permite o envio de imagens, mas que só valida a extensão do arquivo - não o seu conteúdo.

Nesse caso, não tenho conhecimento suficiente sequer pra dar um palpite, então vou me abster de opinar. A presença de um arquivo nocivo por si só não me parece suficiente para se instalar um backdoor (pra isso seria necessário também alguma forma de *shell injection*, mas não tenho certeza). Mas posso estar bastante enganado...

---

P.S. Não acredito que esteja relacionado ao seu problema, mas quando vi que seu sistema usava `mysql_real_escape_string` fiquei com a pulga atrás da orelha - embora não possa garantir nada. Sugiro [esse post no security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/47820/6939) para mais detalhes (leia inclusive os comentários). A princípio, um uso correto e consistente dessa função deve ser bom o suficiente, mas há detalhes a se considerar, por exemplo este que me chamou a atenção:

> Penso que o aspecto mal comumente mal interpretado é que **os valores escapados com `mysql_real_escape_string` somente são destinados a serem usados em um literal para strings do MySQL**. Há casos comuns em que o `mysql_real_escape_string` é usado para dados que não são colocados num literal para strings, mas para alguma outra coisa, tipo, como um identificador, uma palavra-chave, um literal para inteiros, etc.

No seu exemplo *específico* não vejo isso como um problema - pois depois de usar essa função você ainda converte pra `int` e verifica se é numérico, então *até onde eu saiba* (disclaimer: não tenho experiência com PHP) a vulnerabilidade não está aí. De todo modo, verifique se existem outros usos pra essa função que possam apresentar problemas.

Comment: +1 Só o AP vai poder nos dizer se esse era mesmo o problema, mas acho que você matou a charada.

Comment: Na verdade só os testes vão poder responder xD

Comment: Não sei pq, mas ainda não havia pensado em tratar as saídas também, se o script não funcionar ele se torna inútil, pode não resolver, mas pelo menos dificulta um pouco mais para o invasor...

Answer (score 3):

Se você não têm idéia de qual *exploit* está sendo utilizado, começe pela camada de menor nível: o banco de dados.

- **Identifique os padrões**. As 'invasões' sempre acontecem num mesmo horário? Existe algum conteúdo similar entre os registros que afetados? O IP de origem é sempre o mesmo?
- Faça um **cleanup** no banco baseado nos padrões encontrados. (Cuidado com falsos positivos.)
- Crie **triggers** que impeçam a gravação, no banco, de registros que correspondam aos padrões encontrados. Crie um código de erro específico para esta trigger.
- **Monitore** sua aplicação e registre todas as páginas onde uma chamada ao banco gerou o código de erro que você criou.
- Localize, nas páginas afetadas, os pontos frágeis utilizados pelo *exploit*, e elimine-os.