# O que é o PHP Injection? Qual a diferença dele para o SQL Injection? E como evitá-lo?

Tags: php, segurança

- O que é o PHP Injection?
- Qual a diferença dele para o SQL Injection?
- Como evitar o PHP Injection na minha aplicação?
- Quais são as principais formas de ataque do tipo PHP Injection?

## Atualização

**Observação**: Lembrando que o **SQL injection** não é a mesma coisa que o **PHP Injection**.

[Code Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875/best-way-to-avoid-code-injection-in-php)

[What is SQL Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: PHP injection, vc quer dizer abusos de `eval()`, `extract()` e coisas piores como o register globals, magic quotes?

Comment: Wallace não é exatamente/completamente o mesmo assunto mas deve ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10931/3635

Comment: @rray O que um `extract()` pode fazer de mal?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Devido a inúmeros comentários publicados (na época que a pergunta foi feita por mim), creio que há alguma dúvida quanto ao *PHP Injection*.
Então vou explicar alguns pontos.

## O que é PHP Injection?

É uma forma de ataque onde o atacante se utiliza de um script PHP para atacar uma aplicação escrita em PHP.

De acordo com o Google:

> [...] PHP Injection é uma técnica utilizada na internet que consiste em
> injetar scripts maliciosos, fazendo com que a página vulnerável fique
> a controle do atacante [...]

Geralmente, esse tipo ataque se consolida quando o desenvolvedor deixa brechas em formulários de upload. Por exemplo, a pessoa má intencionada pode enviar um script PHP através desse formulário e, em seguida, executá-lo.

O resultado poderá ser desastroso se o atacante conseguir listar diretórios, deletar arquivos, roubar dados sensíveis, etc...

Send assim, *PHP Injection* não tem relação com SQL Injection, como alguns haviam apontado nos comentários anteriores.

## E o SQL Injection?

> SQL Injection é um ataque que consiste na inserção (conhecido como injeção) de uma query via aplicação web.

Ou seja, não há relação direta com o *PHP Injection*.

## Formas de evitar o PHP Injection

**Cuidado na hora de fazer upload!**

Como dito anteriormente, uma das maiores formas desse ataque é através de formulários de upload, onde o atacante manipula o conteúdo enviado (geralmente, enviando um script PHP não esperado no servidor) e, através dele, tem acesso a informações do servidor.

**Evite o `eval`**

Outra coisa perigosa em relação ao *PHP Injection* é a utilização da função `eval`, que tem o poder de tornar uma `string` em um código PHP válido.

Veja mais informações sobre o `eval` na pergunta abaixo:

- [Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128845/eval-%C3%A9-mocinho-ou-bandido)

**Cuidado como o modificador `e` da função `preg_replace`**

Recentemente, o PHP depreciou o modificador `e` da função `preg_replace`, pois esse modificador poderia utilizar um código PHP válido como retorno, sendo também utilizado por atacantes.

Veja que o `preg_replace` e o modificador `e` nessa pergunta causou alguns problemas para o desenvolvedor:

- [O que o código abaixo (escrito por um cracker) faz?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8721/o-que-o-c%C3%B3digo-abaixo-escrito-por-um-cracker-faz)

Nessa pergunta feita pelo @RodrigoBorth, fica claro que o código foi injetado por um cracker no servidor onde fica a aplicação dele.

Apesar de ter sido depreciada, é bom ficar atento em versões antigas de bibliotecas ou aplicações legadas que possam usar esse modificador.

**Null Byte Attack**

Parece que o `Null Byte Attack` também já foi um problema no PHP em versões anteriores também.

Veja mais sobre isso aqui:

- [O que é Null Byte Injection? Como evitá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80760/o-que-%C3%A9-null-byte-injection-como-evit%C3%A1-lo)

## SQL Injection tem relação com o PHP Injection ?

Não. São assuntos diferentes e, em cada caso, o cuidado em relação à segurança deverá será diferente.

Veja sobre SQL Injection na pargunta abaixo para tirar as suas conclusões sobre as diferenças:

- [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php)

## O que mais não confundir?

Outra coisa é confundir `Ataque XSS` com `PHP Injection`.
XSS pode ser feito em qualquer outra linguagem que não tome os devidos cuidados.
PHP Injection é algo específico do PHP.

Comment: Antigamente era comum a prática de fazer includes com base na URL, exemplo `meusite.com/?page=contato` onde `contato` era um arquivo do site, então essa brecha era aproveitada colocando ali o caminho para arquivos maliciosos...

Comment: @KaduAmaral, ainda tem muito código assim, é so ver algumas perguntas ...

Comment: Como eu disse *"não é exatamente/completamente o mesmo assunto mas deve ajudar"*, não discordo da sua pergunta e resposta, tanto que dei +1 pra ambas, o dificil é aturar estes votos pra baixo "roboticos" :( -- parabéns pela resposta!

Answer (score 6):

Apenas para contribuir com a discussão e tendo em vista que passei por esta má experiência em um site que administro vou detalhar o ocorrido.

Neste site é permitido pelo usuário o envio de arquivos ZIP e imagens (JPG/PNG). Pois bem, um infeliz subiu um arquivo JPG que na verdade não era uma imagem e sim um script PHP, ele simplesmente alterou sua extensão, subiu o arquivo com um cabeçalho de imagem obviamente mas no final do arquivo existe um script php que criava um console de acesso remoto com o nome de copyright.php , de lá ele conseguia listar os arquivos do servidor e consequentemente ver eles em detalhe (com direito a conexão ao banco de dados).

Deu trabalho para identificar isso, corrigir foi simples, mas ver a *php injection* acontecendo foi trabalhoso, e cá para nós nunca que você vai imaginar isso. O interessante é que ele tambem usou um browser de texto para visitar a imagem, para vir um cabeçalho binário e na sequência o código ser mostrado no navegador.

Comment: Nem precisa alterar a extensão, dependendo do cenário. Isso é muito comum se o mime magic do apache estiver habilitado, pq ai a extensão é ignorada e são usados metadados para determinar a ação do servidor. Em outras postagens eu já recomendei (ao próprio autor da pergunta, inclusive) justamente desabilitar este recurso. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime_magic.html

Comment: O @Bacco tem um caso de amor com esse `mime_magic`, só pode, kkkkk.

Comment: Valeu pela dica @Bacco , nao sabia dessa fragilidade