# O que é Null Byte Injection? Como evitá-lo?

Tags: string, segurança, null

- O que seria esse `Null Byte Injection`?
- Como evitá-lo?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

É o envio de um *byte* nulo (0) como um texto que mais tarde será usado em alguma parte da aplicação que provavelmente dará acesso a algum recurso que não deveria ser acessado.

Como é comum *strings* serem tratadas com uma sequência de caracteres terminadas com um nulo, isto faria que operações de segurança que adicionam um texto protetor na *string* recebida pela aplicação externamente não considere este texto, já que as funções de comparação de textos param quando encontram um nulo.

Isto é comum nas funções padrões do C (existem algumas novas que não sofrem deste problema). Por isto verificações ou manipulações extras devem ser feitas antes da utilização de textos de origem externa. Como tudo de origem externa.

Linguagens que se valem destas funções sem fazer nenhuma verificação ou manipulação extra sofrem do mesmo problema. PHP sofria com isso no passado, mas hoje sabe como evitar isto em suas funções críticas.

A solução costuma ser simples, já que um nulo raramente é algo correto quando vem de fonte *web*, onde é mais comum o tipo de ataque.

No fundo, esta preocupação específica não é necessária. Se você valida ou limpa dados externos corretamente, como sempre deve fazer, não tem este problema. Este é só um dos caracteres que não devem ser aceitos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Apenas complementando: a referência que me fez fazer a pergunta foi no [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.nullbytes.php), que fala sobre Null Byte Injection, justamente por conta de o PHP usar internamente o C. Parece que o Bug foi corrigido nas versões superiores ao PHP 5.3.4, de acordo com [essa resposta](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48187/null-byte-injection-on-php).