# boas práticas na construção de um CRUD

Tags: php

conexaoBanco.class.php

```
class conexaoBanco{
    private $host="asd";
    private $login="a131";
    private $senha="123123";
    private $banco="asdasdasd";
    private $conn;

    public function dbConexao(){
        $this->conn = new PDO(
            'mysql:host='.$this->host.'; dbname=' .$this->banco.";charset=utf8", $this->login, $this->senha);
        $this->conn->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
        return $this->conn;
    }

}
```

CRUD.class.php

```
include_once("conexaoBanco.class.php");

class CRUD {

    private $db;
    private $tabela = null;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new conexaoBanco();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConexao();
    }

    public function showAll($tabela,$where){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE $where";
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth;
    }
}
```

executando:

```
$sth = $sth->showAll($tabela, "status=0 GROUP BY perfil ASC");
```

quais as boas práticas para se construir um melhor CRUD?

Comment: Evitar sqj injection.

Comment: Evitar XSS attack

Comment: Use um framework, como Laravel, Cakephp ou Symfony. É melhor aprender um deles do que ter que fazer tudo na mão - exceto para casos de aprendizagem :)

Comment: Resumindo, essa pergunta vai gerar respostas muito amplas (ou incompletas) demais. Por isso já votei para o fechamento.

Comment: rsrs, não sei se seria uma boa usar flamework, estou aprendendo + o projeto que estou fazendo não é tão complexo.

Comment: Sempre é bom economizar seu tempo @Denali. Ficar sempre criando funçãozinha e reescrevendo código de validação é besteira e perca de tempo.

Comment: leitura recomendada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php/3869#3869

Comment: leitura recomendada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699/o-que-%C3%A9-o-php-injection-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-dele-para-o-sql-injection-e-como-evit

Comment: Recomendo que use um framework como já comentaram anteriormente! usando um framework você vai ter uma boa noção de como as coisas funcionam e como voce poderia fazer caso queira desenvolver o seu proprio!

Comment: O rapaz está a tentar aprender a criar um `CRUD` com bases sólidas, recomendar frameworks não ajuda em nada.

Comment: Concordo com @edilson, se reabrir faço um crud básico pra ajudar...

Comment: Apesar de ser "anti-framework", concordo com o @WallaceMaxters, caso NÃO seja para aprendizagem, reescrever CRUD é desnecessário.

Comment: Como você faz quando tem que criar seu 13º sistema para sua empresa? reescreve tudo do 0 ? (AI!!!!)