# Expliquem de uma forma mais simples o que são esses ataques?

Tags: segurança, criptografia, sql-injection, keylogger

Gostaria de saber de uma forma mais simplificada o que são esses tipos de ataques.

- Keylogger
- Ataque de força bruta
- Criptoanálise de mangueira de borracha
- Sql injection

E por favor se puderem aprofundar mais no assunto, poderiam me dizer um exemplo simples de como se proteger deles. Estou criando um site para uma empresa e gostaria de entender melhor eles e como me proteger.
Obrigado

Comment: Eu já li varias matérias sobre os 4 tipos de problemas mas preciso intender melhor, se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como acontece um SQL Injection](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100729/como-acontece-um-sql-injection)

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é PHP injection e qual é a diferença entre ele e SQL Injection?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699/o-que-%C3%A9-o-php-injection-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-dele-para-o-sql-injection-e-como-evit)

Comment: É bom dar uma lida no conteúdo já presente no site, assim você pode honrar quem já esforçou para trazer o conteúdo no sentido que você está procurando.

Comment: Não seria melhor criar uma pergunta separada para cada tipo de ataque? A resposta do Renan sumariza bem, mas algumas coisas poderiam ser bem mais detalhadas (há muito a se dizer sobre ataques de força bruta, por exemplo), e não dá pra fazer isso com "4 perguntas em 1"...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- **Keylogger**:

Ocorre quando alguém utiliza hardware ou software para registrar cada tecla que o usuário utilizou. O atacante pode depois fazer uma análise dos textos para encontrar nomes de usuário, senhas, números de contas bancárias etc.

Como se defender: utilize anti-vírus para se proteger da versão em software, uma vez que se trata de malware. A versão em hardware é raríssima - trata-se de um aparelhinho que fica na porta USB, entre o teclado e o computador. Esse é mais fácil de resolver, basta jogar o keylogger fora caso o encontre.

- **Ataque de força bruta**

Trata-se de ficar testando senhas até uma dar certo. Muitos sistemas hoje em dia têm proteções automáticas contra esse tipo de ataque. Se você errar a senha cinco vezes seguidas em um iPhone com o iOS mais atual, por exemplo, o telefone apaga todos os arquivos :D

Esse ataque funciona melhor contra sistemas que não limitam a quantidade máxima de erros de senha, e se o atacante tiver acesso físico a máquina.

Como se defender: garanta uma complexidade mínima de senhas. Não perdõe quem errar a senha mais do que algumas poucas vezes.

- **Criptoanálise de mangueira de borracha**

Esse é o método mais antigo de todos de ataque para se obter informações confidenciais. Trata-se de encher um usuário de porrada até ele dizer as senhas e demais informações confidenciais.

Como se defender: treine seus usuários em artes marciais e manejo de armas de fogo. Dentes falsos com cápsulas de cianureto são uma opção para os membros da equipe que forem mais fracos fisicamente.

- **Sql Injection**

Trata-se de explorar uma falha de programação em geral cometida por pessoas que descobriram o que é SQL há pouco tempo. Ocorre quando um programa passa para uma consulta SQL um dado informado pelo usuário, sem fazer qualquer tratamento sobre esse *input*.

Como se defender: nunca deixe seu sistema nas mãos apenas de um iniciante. A equipe de desenvolvimento precisa ter pelo menos um profissional experiente para evitar não apenas esse, como também outros tipos de falhas de programação que podem ser causadas por falta de experiência.

Comment: Acerca de SQL injection, não acontece só com iniciantes @Renan, à vários tipos de SQL injection, error based, union based, blind. Qualquer sistema pode estar vulnerável, uns mais que outros. Aqui está dois videos bastante interessantes acerca disso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUv9XPgeUww , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBVThFwdYTc

Comment: @Miguel todos esses tipos de injeção são possíveis quando o código tem vulnerabilidades extremamente básicas. Eu continuo achando que são coisas de iniciante. Na empresa onde trabalho nós realizamos testes de habilidade antes de contratar qualquer pessoa. Se o candidato expõe o código a qualquer ameaça de injeção de SQL - não importa o tipo - nós não oferecemos mais do que uma vaga de estágio.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo e simples
Um ataque de força bruta nada mais é que um bot ou uma rede de bots (robôs) que tentam pelo método “tentativa e erro” acertar a sua senha. Conseguindo o acesso ele captura a sua senha e volta mais tarde através de uma invasão, de certa forma pela porta da frente do seu site.
Forma de se proteger: criar e trocar com frequência senhas fortes, que contenham pelo menos 8 caracteres, letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, números e caracteres especiais (!@#$%ˆ&*), e não colocando palavras conhecidas ou fáceis de serem descobertas, melhor ainda que sejam totalmente aleatórias.
manter seu computador (principalmente se nele rodar o sistema operacional Windows em qualquer versão) limpo e longe de vírus, com verificações frequentes com bons antivírus (aquele antivírus gratuito nem sempre resolve).
nunca, jamais e sob qualquer hipótese salvar senhas no seu computador ou pedir para que o navegador/browser salve para futuros acessos.

keylogger:  (ou registrador de teclas), apesar de muitas vezes entendi como spyware, é um programa de computador cuja finalidade é registrar tudo o que é digitado em um teclado, na maioria das vezes objetivando capturar senhas, números de cartão de crédito e outras informações importantes. Ele tem um funcionamento típico de vírus, pois é instalado e atua sem que o usuário perceba sua presença.
Forma de se proteger: Manter um antivírus atualizado é fundamental, ainda mais atualmente quando estamos quase o tempo todos conectado a internet, baixando arquivos, trocando música, vídeos e testando programas e jogos.

Sql Injection:  é um ataque que consiste na inserção (conhecido como injeção) de uma query via aplicação web. A Locaweb sempre toma todas as precauções em relação a atualizações para evitar quaisquer brechas de segurança nos sites hospedados.
Entretanto às vezes surgem vulnerabilidades que são exploradas através de programação, de nada adiantando as precauções que tomamos.
Tais vulnerabilidades estão presentes em códigos (ASP, PHP, etc.) colocados pelos próprios clientes. Este é o caso da "SQL Injection", brecha através da qual um invasor pode executar queries ou statements arbitrários numa base relacional via "injeção" de comandos em campos de formulários.
Forma de se proteger: Usando a função addslashes() tem o mesmo efeito que habilitar magic quotes, porém só aplica onde for conveniente. O que ela faz é colocar um caracter de escapa antes das aspas simples ou dupla, antes da barra invertida e do caracter NULL.
Usar 'prepared statements' ao invés do próprio código SQL atribuíndo todas as outras medidas de prevenção usar esta, nos daria mais performace e segurança, além de ser mais simples de ler e escrever. Porem só pode ser usado em SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE, DELETE e CREATE TABLE.
$login = $_GET['login'] $query = "SELECT * FROM registos WHERE login = '$login'";
Ficaria assim:
$query = "SELECT * FROM registos WHERE login = OR 1";

Criptoanálise de mangueira de borracha: Na criptografia, criptoanálise de mangueira de borracha é a extorsão de segredos criptográficos (por exemplo, a senha para um arquivo cifrado) de uma pessoa por coação ou tortura,[1] [2] em contraste com o ataque de criptoanálise matemática ou técnica. O eufemismo refere-se a golpear alguém com uma mangueira de borracha até que ela coopere.
Forma de se proteger: Treinamento aos usuários para qualquer tipo de tortura.