# Utilizar um caminho absoluto em uma função require() é o suficiente para prevenir ataques?

Tags: php

O uso da função `dirname(__FILE__)` ou da constante mágica `__DIR__` é apropriadamente segura para impossibilitar um local file inclusion ou um remote file inclusion em um `require()` que recebe parâmetros por GET?

Há uma solução para este problema?

Comment: Puts, comecei a responder, mas agora que vi esse tal de "directory transversal" ...

Comment: Seria no caso do usuário modificar a URL para colocar um " ../../../arquivo.txt" para obter arquivos que não estão na pasta especificada, mas em diretórios acima ou até mesmo em diretórios remotos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Colocar o caminho absoluto para diretórios evita acessar outras pastas?

Não. Pois se o "atacante" colocar `../`, sabendo o caminho do arquivo, ele pode acessar um diretório indesejado de qualquer forma.

Ou seja, para a seguinte estrutura abaixo:

```
app/
    database.php
web/
    index.php
    pages/
       home.php
       contact.php
```

Se o `web/index.php` é a "raiz" do seu aplicativo, mas o usuário mal intencionado colocar o `?page=../app/database.php`, ele teoricamente estaria fazendo com o que o PHP efetue o `include` normalmente.

Para você entender. Tudo isso abaixo resulta na mesma operação

```
include 'app/database.php';

include __DIR__ . '/app/database.php'

#supondo que estamos na pasta 'web'

include __DIR__ . '../app/database.php';
```

Observe que fornecer um nome absoluto para o diretório raiz de determinado diretório ou arquivo desejado não impede que outros arquivos (fora dele) sejam acessados.

Nesse caso, acho muito apropriado que, para carregamento de páginas através de `get`, se façam funções com tratamentos específicos.

Exemplo:

```
function page_include($page)
{

    if (strpos($page, '..') !== false) {
       throw new Exception("Caractere inválido detectado");
    }

    include WEB_DIRECTORY . '/pages/' . $page;
}
```

<sub>Talvez isso seja algo básico. Você poderia incluir outras verificações, evitando ataques.</sub>

> Remote file inclusion (inclusão remota de arquivos)

`allow_url_include` é uma configuração que permite você usar o `include` em urls (o que eu não acho nada bom). Sobre isso recomendo que você desative a configuração `allow_url_include`, pois nesse caso, permitir tal configuração é dar sua aplicação de mãos-beijadas na mão de pessoas mal intencionadas.

> PHP injection

É um outro problema comum envolvendo arquivos ou pastas em PHP.
Leia sobre isso aqui: [O que é o PHP Injection? Qual a diferença dele para o SQL Injection? E como evitá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699/o-que-%C3%A9-o-php-injection-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-dele-para-o-sql-injection-e-como-evit)

Comment: E no caso se o usuário informasse `file:///etc/passwd` por exemplo, não haveria os dois pontos para serem pegos no "filtro", mas isso também funcionaria? Ví em um exemplo do livro Pro PHP Security e isso me deixou confuso.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri tenho que dar uma olhada sobre os wrappers do php. Só um minuto..

Comment: @RenanCavalieri com `file:///` também dá pra colocar os `../`

Comment: Sim, eu digo em relação a sua solução de colocar um IF para barra os dois pontos, no caso do exemplo que tirei do livro a string não possui os dois pontos, logo não iria entrar no IF.