# Como manter a variável com o mesmo valor no banco de dados?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Estou com uma dúvida no código abaixo:

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";  

$id = $_POST["id"];
$nome = isset((trim(ucwords($_POST["nome"])))) : (trim(ucwords($_POST["nome"]))) : 
$apelido = trim(ucwords($_POST["apelido"]));
$telefone = trim($_POST ["telefone"]);
$celular = trim($_POST ["celular"]);
$email = strtolower($_POST ["email"]);
$endereco = $_POST ["endereco"];
$num_end = $_POST ["num_end"]; 

//Query para atualizar os dados no banco; 
$sql = "UPDATE `clientes` SET nome = '$nome', apelido = '$apelido', telefone = '$telefone', celular = '$celular', email = '$email', endereco = '$endereco', num_end = '$num_end' WHERE ID = '$id'"; 

//Executa a query;
$query = $conecta->query($sql);

//Fecha a conexão; 
$conecta->close(); 
echo "Dados atualizados com sucesso! :)";                   
?>
```

Como que eu faço para manter o valor no banco de dados se eu deixar o campo "nome" em branco, por exemplo?

Porque se eu deixar:

```
$nome = isset((trim(ucwords($_POST["nome"])))) : (trim(ucwords($_POST["nome"]))) : "";
```

Ele irá alterar no banco de dados o nome e deixar em branco, mas eu quero que o valor que já estava lá salvo no banco se mantenha.

É muito complicado? Me desculpem pela pergunta boba, mas procurei em diversos fóruns algo parecido mas não encontrei.

Answer (score 3):

Isso deve resolver:

```
if($nome == ''){
   $nome = null;
} 

$sql = "UPDATE `clientes` SET nome = coalesce('$nome', nome), apelido = '$apelido', telefone = '$telefone', celular = '$celular', email = '$email', endereco = '$endereco', num_end = '$num_end' WHERE ID = '$id'";
```

O operador de comparação [coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) retorna o primeiro valor **não nulo** que foi passado pra ele.

Comment: Eu deixei assim: 

$nome = (trim(ucwords($_POST["nome"])));
if ($nome == ''){
 $nome = null;
}


$sql = "UPDATE `clientes` SET nome = coalesce('$nome', nome), apelido = coalesce('$apelido', apelido), telefone = coalesce('$telefone', telefone), celular = coalesce('$celular', celular), email = coalesce('$email', email), endereco = coalesce('$endereco', endereco), num_end = coalesce('$num_end', num_end) WHERE ID = '$id'"; 

Porém, quando eu mudo só o apelido por exemplo, o nome fica em branco.

Answer (score 2):

Uma das maneiras é gerar a própria *query* condicionalmente:

```
// cria um array vazio.
$campos = array(); 

// se houver algum valor em $nome, adiciona "nome='$nome'" em $campos
if(!empty($nome))    $campos[] = " nome    = '$nome'";
// repete a lógica para todos opcionais:
if(!empty($apelido)) $campos[] = " apelido = '$apelido'";
...
```

e assim por diante.

Em seguida:

```
if(count($campos)) { // se algum campo for preenchido
   $sql = 'UPDATE `clientes` SET '.implode(',',$campos).' WHERE ID = $id'; 
   ... executa a query ...
}
```

## Importante!

Independente da solução escolhida, é fundamental aprender evitar injeções de SQL, por uma questão de segurança:

> [Como acontece um SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100729/70)

> [O que é o PHP Injection? Qual a diferença dele para o SQL Injection? E como evitá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699/70)

> [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/70) (não é mysqli, mas a lógica é a mesma)