# Usar .htacess para alterar site para outro idioma

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigavel, diretório

Boa tarde,

Tenho um site que precisar ter a versão em inglês, portanto pensei em ter uma pasta /eng/ e apenas mudar essa url porém o site em português já utilizo htacess para ter url amigavel que dentro da raíz normal puxas as páginas de dentro de uma pasta chamada /pages/ e ai preciso fazer com que quando for em inglês ele puxe dentro da pasta /eng/pages/.

Estou tentando fazer mas ele não consegue carregar a página na pasta certa.

Meu .htacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^eng/([a-z_-]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]


<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</files>
```

Minha index

```
<?php 
    require 'header.php';
    include $url.$page;
    require 'footer.php';
?>
```

Tenho um arguivo que gera a variável $page

```
 $page = (isset($_GET['page']) and !empty($_GET['page']))? "pages/{$_GET['page']}.php" : "pages/home.php";  
  if (!file_exists($page)): $page = "pages/404.php"; endif;
```

Se alguém conseguir me dar uma luz eu agradeço.

Comment: Parece que seu site está vulnerável a [PHP Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699/o-que-%C3%A9-o-php-injection-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-dele-para-o-sql-injection-e-como-evit)

Comment: Olá Guilherme, obrigado pela dica, mas aproveitando sempre achei que eu deveria me preocupar com esse tipo de segurança quando houvesse alguma conexão com sql, mysql, ou seja, login ou painel esse tipo de coisas. Estou pensando errado?

Comment: De uma olhada no link, PHP Injection é diferente de SQL Injection. Com ele um atacante poderia excluir todos os arquivos do seu servidor, mesmo que não haja nenhuma conexão com banco de dados, não é muito interessante perder arquivos estáticos

Comment: Ahhhh show então, vou dar uma olhada sim, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode mudar a linha que redireciona para:

```
RewriteRule ^eng/([a-z_-]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&lang=eng [NC,L]
```

E na hora de buscar o arquivo verifica a linguagem:

```
$page = (isset($_GET['lang']) and $_GET['lang'] == "eng")? "eng/" : "";
$page += (isset($_GET['page']) and !empty($_GET['page']))? "pages/{$_GET['page']}.php" : "pages/home.php";
```

Comment: Gabriel deu certo porém fiz algumas mudanças que me gerou outro problema. Vou respostar logo abaixo:

Answer (score 0):

No momento em que fiz a alteração sugerida do Gabriel, alterei algumas coisas e funcionou como preciso porém me trouxe outro problema, eu não queria ter que duplicar todos os arquivos mudar apenas o caminho da pasta /page/ arquivos js ou css entre outro gostaria que continuassem tendo o caminho base no fim para que possa entender vou posta o code mais completo, eu altero o caminho para minha variável $url.

Este é o meu config

```
<?php 
  session_start();

  if(isset($_POST['lang'])):
    session_destroy($_SESSION['langAtual']);
    session_destroy($_SESSION['urlAtual']);
    if($_POST['lang']=='eng'):
        $_SESSION['langAtual'] = $_POST['lang']; 
        $_SESSION['urlAtual'] = "http://talktoall.com.br/clientes/factor/eng/";
        echo $_SESSION['urlAtual'];
    elseif($_POST['lang']=='pt'):
        $_SESSION['langAtual'] = $_POST['lang']; 
        $_SESSION['urlAtual'] = "http://talktoall.com.br/clientes/factor/";
        echo $_SESSION['urlAtual'];
    endif;
  endif;

  if(empty($_SESSION['langAtual'])):
    $_SESSION['urlAtual'] = "http://talktoall.com.br/clientes/factor/";
  endif;

  $url = $_SESSION['urlAtual'];


  if(isset($_GET['page']) and !empty($_GET['page'])):    
    if(isset($_SESSION['langAtual']) and $_SESSION['langAtual'] == "eng"):
      $page = "eng/pages/{$_GET['page']}.php";
    else:
      $page = "/pages/{$_GET['page']}.php";
    endif;
  else:
    $page = "pages/home.php";
  endif;

  if ($page == "pages/admin.php"): header("Location: ./index.php"); endif;
  if ($page == "pages/enviar-colaborador.php"): if(empty($_POST['email'])): header('Location: '.$url); exit; endif; endif;
  if (!file_exists($page)): $page = "pages/404.php"; endif;

?>
```

Aqui minha index

```
<?php require 'config.php'; ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=$url?>css/custom.css">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=$url?>css/owl.carousel.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=$url?>css/bootstrap-submenu.min.css"> 
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <title>Factor</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="hidden" name="p" id="p" value="<?=$_GET['page']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="" id="" value="<?=$page?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="" id="" value="<?=$_SESSION['langAtual']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="<?=$url?>">
    <?php 
      require 'header.php';
      include $page;
      require 'footer.php';
    ?>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="<?=$url?>js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAg8O_C28sofvtTvMldCqUjkU5A5S8l8NI&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?=$url?>js/imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=$url?>js/bootstrap-submenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?=$url?>js/main.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```