# selecinar conteudo de outra pagina e mostrar no index

Tags: php

Boa noite, estou tentando selecionar uma pagina para mostrar seu conteudo dentro do index, mas apresenta um erro e não estou conseguido resolves.

Alguem pode me ajudar por favor?

> Notice: Undefined index: p in C:\wamp64\www\afiliados2\welcome.php on line 89

CODIGO

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <?php echo " <a href=\"#\"></a> ";
        $pagina = $_GET['p']; if(isset($pagina)){include $pagina;} <!--LINNHA DO ERRO-->
        ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o próprio erro já diz:

> Índice `p` não está definido.

Você está buscando o valor de `p` que deveria ser recebido via `GET`. Mas não recebeu!

O correto é fazer a verificação ao buscar na variável `$_GET`. Veja:

```
$pagina = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : false;
// Sintaxe curta (disponível desde o PHP 7):
// $pagina = $_GET['p'] ?? false;

if ($pagina) { include $pagina; }
```

> Não é o objetivo da pergunta, mas vale a pena alertar-te: **você está "incluindo" um arquivo recebido via URL**. Logo, fica "facinho" alguém injetar um script no seu servidor. Veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699/o-que-%C3%A9-o-php-injection-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-dele-para-o-sql-injection-e-como-evit) que relata sobre este assunto. Mas você pode, também, dá uma "[googlada](https://www.google.com/search?q=GET%20injection%20php&oq=GET%20injection%20php)" que vai entender mais.

Comment: boa noite. O erro foi resolvido mas agora esta dando pagina em branco, saberia me diser o porque?. Estou grato pela sua ajuda.

Comment: Então, colega. Quando a variável `p` não foi passada via `GET`, seu script **não tem nada para incluir**. Basta você chegar a sua *URL*: `http://localhost/index.php?p=pagina_a_ser_incluida.php`.

Comment: @everson note que minha resposta está DIRETAMENTE relacionada à sua pergunta. Não vai ser interessante você mudar o rumo da sua pergunta. Já entendi que você está com dificuldade de entender sobre o assunto. Nesta pergunta, o máximo que posso fazer é te dar uma dica sobre o novo problema, que na realidade não é um erro, mas sim uma utilização errada da sua aplicação... [Veja esse vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ7XkXOwKuA) que vc vai entender o funcionamento disso aí, já que o objetivo aqui é sanar problemas, e não criar um tutorial pra te ensinar tudo sobre método `GET`...

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda novamente, agora esta tudo executando bem, vi o erro que tinha e fiz as alterações.