# Problemas para alterar dados de uma tabela sql com php

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, plpgsql

Quero fazer um sistema de alteração de dados com PHP e SQL. Segue o código PHP e SQL.

```
'if (isset($_POST['alterar'])) {

    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $cpf = $_POST["cpf"];
    $nascimento = $_POST["nascimento"];
    $numero = $_POST["numero"];
    $cargo = $_POST["cargo"];
    $rua = $_POST["rua"];
    $numerocasa = $_POST["numerocasa"];
    $bairro = $_POST["bairro"];

    
    $pgsql_connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=avanteparkdb user=postgres password=1234") or die("Sem conexão com o servidor");
    pg_query($pgsql_connection, $query);

    $sql = "update pessoa_fisica set (nome='$nome', cpf='$cpf', nascimento='$nascimento', numero='$numero', 0) returning idpf);";

    $sql = "update endereco set (endid='$idpf', rua='$rua', numerocasa='$numerocasa', bairro='$bairro');";

    $sql = "update funcionarios set (endereco = '$idpf' where idpf = $idpf);";
    pg_query($pgsql_connection, $query);

    $result=pg_query($dbconn,$query);

        pg_close($dbconn);

    echo "<script> parent.self.location = \"gerenciamento.php\";</script>";


}

?>'
```

Pesquisei em vários sites em como usar o UPDATE de forma correta mas não achei nenhuma solução.

Comment: Você está definindo `$sql = ` 3 vezes, consequentemente a última definição apaga as outras 2. Tem que decidir se vai querer executar um pg_query para cada uma, ou se vai concatenar com `$sql .= ` e executar pg_query uma única vez. Da onde vem $query, usada em `pg_query($pgsql_connection, $query);`? Remove os parenteses das querys de update. Além desses problemas, existe um problema maior referente à [sql injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699/o-que-%c3%a9-o-php-injection-qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-dele-para-o-sql-injection-e-como-evit).

Comment: Também falta definir o where de algumas das querys de update.

Comment: No caso esse é um projeto individual, não precisarei me preocupar com sql injection por enquanto. Mas então, como devo aplicar o where?

Comment: Se você não definir um where, o update vai ser feito em todas as linhas da tabela, o mais comum é que se use a chave primária no where.

Comment: Obrigada, consegui consertar :)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tenta tirar todos os parênteses nas querys de update após o `SET` e me fala se deu certo, provavelmente o erro que esteja dando seja por causa disso.

[EDIT]

Analisando um pouco mais seu código, vejo alguns erros de sintaxe.
Em todas as querys tem ";" dentro da query, deixa apenas o ";" fora das aspas, e na sua variável $idpf na última query está sem aspas simples, assim dando erro.

**Código corrigido**

```
$sql = "update pessoa_fisica set nome='$nome', cpf='$cpf', nascimento='$nascimento', numero='$numero', 0 returning idpf)";

$sql = "update endereco set endid='$idpf', rua='$rua', numerocasa='$numerocasa', bairro='$bairro'";

$sql = "update funcionarios set endereco = '$idpf' where idpf = '$idpf'";
pg_query($pgsql_connection, $query);
```

Comment: Olá, não funcionou.

Comment: Ele executa, porém nada muda na tabela.

Comment: @anabananapj atualizei a resposta, tenta novamente.

Comment: ainda nada, creio que o erro esteja na lógica do meu código, agradeço a ajuda desde já.

Comment: Como o Benilson falou nos comentários acima, faltam muitas coisas no código, inclusive os `WHERE` nas querys sql e a variável `$query` no `pg_query` não existe, teria que colocar uma das variáveis de update, que inclusive estão todas com o mesmo nome, uma sobrescrevendo a outra.

Comment: Obrigada, consegui consertar :)